# Can not find camera on Macbook

Tags: ios, xcode

I've followed a tutorial to create an app that preview the camera and the first step is to list the media devises that can be used.

But I'm getting a list of zero devises and my macbook camera is nowhere to be found.

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    let captureSession = AVCaptureSession()
    var previewLayer : AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer?
    var captureDevice : AVCaptureDevice?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        captureSession.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPresetHigh
        let devices = AVCaptureDevice.devices()
        println("FOOBAR")
        println(devices.count)

        for device in devices {
            println("HELLO")
            if (device.hasMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo)) {
                if(device.position == AVCaptureDevicePosition.Back) {
                    captureDevice = device as? AVCaptureDevice
                    if captureDevice != nil {
                        println("Capture device found")
                        beginSession()
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    }

    func beginSession() {

    }


}
```

Comment: Usually the camera is right in the middle of the bezel of the display facing the user.  (Sorry, couldn't resist because of how you stated it in the title :-))

Answer (score 0):

I would remove the check for `device.position == AVCaptureDevicePosition.Back`. In my experience, `device.position` always seems to return `nil` on Mac OS X.